# Gson converting any integer to 0 when using fromJson

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

This is the POJO:

```
public class MyPojo {
  String id;
  double myNumber;
}
```

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "id": "id1",
    "my_number": 10.0
}
```

This is my conversion code:

```
// from is the JSON String from Above
Map<String, Object> myData = gson.fromJson(new String(from, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Map.class);
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(myData);  // I checked - this contains "myNumber: 10"
MyPojo pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, MyPojo.class);  // This contains "myNumber: 0"
```

`myNumber` in the `pojo` object is always `0`

In my json I renamed it to `myNumber` and that didn't work either.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it so that I don't lose the value of the int?
Thanks

Comment: `my_number` is not equal to `myNumber` – meaning that the mapping is not correct in your case. You either configure the JSON name in the POJO (there is an annotation for that), or you change the name of the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_number` is not equal to `myNumber` – meaning that the mapping is not correct in your case. You either have to configure the JSON name in the POJO (there is an annotation for that – @SerializedName), or you have to change the name of the attribute.

I prefer the first approach, so you change the POJO like this:

```
public final class MyPojo 
{
  String id;

  @SerializedName( "my_number" )
  double myNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. At first it didn't work cuz Pulsar was pulling `Gson` and I was unkowingly using an older version of `Gson`. After using the latest `2.10.1` this is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As tquadrat mentioned my_number and myNumber are seprate when you are using GSON library to deserialize.

To deserialize it in double you need to use @SerializedName("my_number").

```
class MyPojo {
    String id;

    @SerializedName("my_number")
    double myNumber;
}
```

and code to convert it to Pojo :

```
 String json = "{\n" +
            "    \"id\": \"id1\",\n" +
            "    \"my_number\": 10.0\n" +
            "}";
    
    MyPojo myPojo = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyPojo.class);
    System.out.println(myPojo);
```